# Separating a string into a 2d array using two different splits

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, split

I'm trying to input values into a CSV using a 2d array. I have a string which is separated by ',' to separate the values and ';' to separate each row.

string below;

```
text = 536924636,www.microsoft.com,http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW;536924733,www.microsoft.com,http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi;536925898,crl.microsoft.com,http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/product;
```

I want to be able to split the rows into a 2d array like so

```
arr = reg.split([','][';'])
```

So that that it ends up like this;

```
arr =[ 
['536924636','www.microsoft.com','http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW'],
['536924733','www.microsoft.com','http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi'],
['536924636','www.microsoft.com','http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW']]
```

but when I attempt this, I get the following error;

```
  arr = reg.split([','][';'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can anyone help me achive this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `split()` will split *one* string into *one* list. You can't make it produce two dimensions by passing it two parameters instead of one.

But you can call it twice, once for each delimiter:

```
>>> text = "536924636,www.microsoft.com,http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW;536924733,www.microsoft.com,http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi;536925898,crl.microsoft.com,http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/product;"
>>> [r.split(",") for r in [r for r in text.split(";")]]
[
['536924636', 'www.microsoft.com', 'http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW'], 
['536924733', 'www.microsoft.com', 'http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi'], 
['536925898', 'crl.microsoft.com', 'http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/product'], 
['']
]
```

Comment: Alternatively, `[r.split(',') for r in text.split(';')]`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach can be

```
arr = [i.split(',') for i in text.split(';')]
```

Comment: I get the following error ;
```
    arr = [[i] for i in arr.split(';')]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Your solution causes each entry to be double-nested lists, as your image also shows. It should not have `[]` around the `i.split(',')` part.

Comment: That's true! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = str(input())
arr  = x.split(";")
finalArr = []
for items in arr:
    arr2 = []
    arr2.append(items)
    finalArr.append(arr2)
print(finalArr)
```

Try this out. I am hoping this is what you are looking for.